# Server sent event with fields other than data not being sent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-sent-events

I'm attempting to setup a node js server to stream some events via SSE and I cannot get it to work unless I start the stream with the `data` field.

When i try and include other fields for example `id` or `event` they dont show in the chrome inspector?

If I attempt to put these field before data no events other than the connection opening occurs.

Here is the route that I am playing around with.

```
router.get('/stream', function * (){
    let stream = new PassThrough();
    let send = (message, id) => stream.write(`id: ${JSON.stringify(id)}\n data: ${JSON.stringify(message)}\n\n`);    
    let finish = () => dispatcher.removeListener('message', send);    
    this.socket.setTimeout(Number.MAX_VALUE);
    this.type = 'text/event-stream;charset=utf-8';
    this.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    this.set('Connection', 'keep-alive');    
    this.body = stream;
    stream.write(': open stream\n\n');

    dispatcher.on('message', send);
    this.req.on('close', finish);
    this.req.on('finish', finish);
    this.req.on('error', finish);
    setInterval(function(){
        dispatcher.emit('message', {date: Date.now()}, '12345')
    }, 5000)
});
```

I am not too certain if I am writing to the stream correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, it was indeed a malformed event stream. There isnt supposed to be a space between the fields. It should instead be:

`id: ${JSON.stringify(id)}\ndata: ${JSON.stringify(message)}\n\n`